# How to get JS code running on mobile while it minimized or sleep

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, google-chrome, mobile

I'm getting a trouble while running JS code in a browser.
I've got a small web page which uses HTML5 location API for tracking a user.
User opens my website, logs in, and goes to a certain page on which I'm using location API to track user's location. Everything works fine until user's phone goes to sleep or user presses "home" button to minimize browser. The same thing happens on both Android and iPhone.

Is there any way to prevent the phone from going to sleep and let JS code work while browser is minimized?

Answer (score 0):

one of the way I found is using video on a page where all JS located. but another problem is - screen became always ON, which can cause battery to discharge too fast (if I turn off screen manually using power button everything stops working)..

still looking for some ideas...